# Python Docstring Comments, Greater Than and Less Than Symbols Not Showing

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, docstring

I'm commenting Python code using docstrings. Note, this is just an example,

```
def credit_bonus(self, num_purchases: int, total_spend: float)->int:
    '''
    Calculates eligible and additional credit bonus for a customer, compared to previous
    yearly spends, and number of previous purchases.

    Additional credit ranking of 2, if current number of purchases > previous purchaces, 
    and current spend >= 95% previous spend.

    Return: customer's credit ranking
    '''

    ....

    return credit_rank
```

When the comment is displayed for this function, in VSCode, when hovering over this function in another module it is called from, the greater than symbol is not displayed. I have tried various escape characters, `&gt;`, so far nothing works.

Is it possible to dispay, < and >, in Python docstrings?

Also, I know this is not a show stopper, nor imperative, just a minor convenience, will end up typing, greater than, instead.

Thanks and regards, njc

Comment: Did you try `&lt;derp>` ?

Comment: @aerijman, just tried it, still no show.

Comment: from my total ignoraance, searching for potential restructuredtext options I found `:math:\`\sqrt{16}\`` or also unicode options: `&#8805;` `&#x2265;` `&GreaterEqual;`

Comment: @aerijman thanks for your help, I think I'll call it a day on this, can't get it working. Funny enough, just about any other special character, or symbol, comes through, not these two.

Comment: if only `>` is in the comment it works for me, `<foobar>` does not show, aerijman's trick with `&lt;foobar>` works but does not look nice. You should file a bug with ms-python extension and request they should HTML-escape the doc strings in the tooltips

Comment: @rioV8, managed to get aerijman's `&lt;foobar>` working too, will take up your suggestion, and send ms-python this issue, or check out a doc extension.

Answer (score 0):

Working for function / method DocStrings, not for Class. Since posting, I'm still typing < and > in DocStrings, and I have noticed where it (now?) works, and where it doesn't. First some specs;

- Windows 10 Pro x64 20H2
- Visual Studio Code x64 1.52.1
- Microsoft Python extension for Visual Studio Code 2020.12.424452561

I does work for functions or methods,

```
def __new_connection(self)->sqlite3.Connection:
    '''
     __new_connection(self)`->`sqlite3.Connection:\n
     create a new connection using a connection string, time out, and isolation level settings.\n

     return:
         sqlite3.Connection.
    '''
    return sqlite3.connect(database=self.__con_str, timeout=self.__timeout, isolation_level=None, uri=True)
```

Typing the, acute or back quote, around the `>`, or in this case `->`, will display < and > symbols, when the DocString is displayed for the method's description.

**But**

For class docstrings, it doesn't work.

```
class Broker:
    '''
     class wrapper for sqlite3 database objects and operations.\n
     transaction type: auto-commit.\n
     database type: file system database. not in-memory (:memory:)
     isolation level is set to None, i.e. auto-commit, cache is private.

     methods:\n
         __new_connection(self)->sqlite3.Connection
         creates a new sqlite3 connection object

         __cursor_execute(self, conn: sqlite3.Connection, sqlCmd: str, params: tuple=())->sqlite3.Cursor
        creates a cursor object, execute a parameterised sql statement
    '''
```

Doesn't work, no matter what symbol, or mark up, are placed around the < or >.

I shall post again if I find a work around for class DocStrings, assuming it doesn't work (still), if I do.

Thanks and regards,
njc